# Can i use custom list to appear in a alert dialog?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, custom-adapter

I have created a custom adapter to display different images in the each list items from the drawable resource.
Now the custom adapter is working good in a listview.
Now i need to display the list in a alertdialog or any other instead of displaying in another layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display it on a regular subactivity that looks like a dialog instead.

Comment: But when using subactivity the previous layout will not be visible in the background right?

Comment: @Arun prasath: The subactivity will be as big as you set it to be. Change its dimensions so that it doesn't take the full screen, and the parent activity will be seen in the background.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet shows a custom list inside a dialog box... :

```
        Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(Activity.this);
        ListView modeList = new ListView(Activity.this);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);


            builder.setTitle(" results[s] ");
            MySimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(Activity.this, data , R.layout.list_main, 
                    new String[] { "name", "distance" ,"phone","web"}, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle ,R.id.item_subtitle1 ,R.id.item_subtitle2});
            modeList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }





        builder.setView(modeList);
        dialog2 = builder.create();
        dialog2.show();
```